# Creating landscape page-spanning tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex, landscape

I have a large table I want to include in a LaTeX document. It is too wide for a page, so I want to rotate it 90 degrees and have it landscape. Then it will be too tall for the page, so I want it to span multiple pages.

I have managed to get it landscape with:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htdp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|l|c|l|c|c|c}
     [ Data here ]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

So the question is, how can I now get it to span multiple pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [longtable package](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).